# How to finish the sprite animation in Update_Hit function first before going back to walking state?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

This is the code I have for switching states:

```
    if (mCurrentState == State.Walking)
    {
        action = "stand";
        Update_Stand(gameTime);

        if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) == true)
        {
            action = "run";
            feetPosition.X += MOVE_LEFT;
            effect = SpriteEffects.None;

            Update_Run(gameTime);

        }
        else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) == true)
        {
            action = "run";
            feetPosition.X += MOVE_RIGHT;
            effect = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;

            Update_Run(gameTime);
        }

        if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z) == true)
        {
            mCurrentState = State.Hitting;
        }
    }

    if (mCurrentState == State.Hitting)
    {
        action = "hit";

        Update_Hit(gameTime);

        mCurrentState = State.Walking;
    }
```

My Update_Hit(GameTime gameTime) method is something like that. I have 2 sprites to animate.

```
public void Update_Hit(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Check if it is a time to progress to the next frame
        if (nextFrame_Hit >= frameInterval_Hit)
        {
            // Progress to the next frame in the row
            currentFrame_Hit.X++;

            // If reached end of the row advance to the next row, reset to the first frame 
            if (currentFrame_Hit.X >= sheetSize_Hit.X)
            {
                currentFrame_Hit.X = 0;
                currentFrame_Hit.Y++;
            }

            // If reached last row in the frame sheet, jump to the first row again
            if (currentFrame_Hit.Y >= sheetSize_Hit.Y)
                currentFrame_Hit.Y = 0;

            // Reset time interval for next frame
            nextFrame_Hit = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
        else
        {
            // Wait for the next frame
            nextFrame_Hit += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
        }
    }
```

How do I get the hit animation to complete before changing state back to walking?

Comment: Does frameInterval_Hit ever reach zero?

Comment: // Amount of time between frames is the
TimeSpan frameInterval_Hit;

// Time passed since last frame is the
TimeSpan nextFrame_Hit;

Comment: So you want to run the animation until it has gone through all the rows, and you want it to loop the frame set as long as the z key is held down; does that sound right?

Comment: I want to run the animation until it has gone through all the rows even z key is not held down anymore. After the animation is completely finished, it goes back to walking state.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I also want to force the animation to finish first before the player can trigger the new animation.

Comment: You can get better advice in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using fixed game time, you need to make sure you are not changing states before the animation is complete to ensure that on each update you get a single frame of your animation until the animation is complete:

```
if (nextFrame_Hit >= frameInterval_Hit)
{
    // Progress to the next frame in the row
    currentFrame_Hit.X++;

    // If reached end of the row advance to the next row, reset to the first frame 
    if (currentFrame_Hit.X >= sheetSize_Hit.X)
    {
        currentFrame_Hit.X = 0;
        currentFrame_Hit.Y++;
    }

    // If reached last row in the frame sheet, jump to the first row again
    if (currentFrame_Hit.Y >= sheetSize_Hit.Y)
    {
        currentFrame_Hit.Y = 0;
        mCurrentState = State.Walking;
    }

    // Reset time interval for next frame
    nextFrame_Hit = TimeSpan.Zero;
}
else
{
    // Wait for the next frame
    nextFrame_Hit += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
}
```

and you need to change to this:

```
if (mCurrentState == State.Hitting)
{
    action = "hit";

    Update_Hit(gameTime);

}
```

Comment: It doen't work. When I keep holding the Z key, the animation stuck there and it returns to walking state after I released the Z key.

Comment: so it is not animating it sticks on the first frame?

Comment: Ya. It sticks on the first frame.

Comment: I just share code for convenience. It's hard to explain.  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mjmqxardtz9q9m/Code.rar

Comment: I made a very small change. Any difference?

Comment: I edited my answer to fix it I think, the only draw back is that now you are not going to be able to 'walk' and 'hit' at the same time. You would need to set up a separate flag for hitting to make it work and then handle the hitting while moving with different sprites.

Comment: Thanks for helping me a lot but I still have some issues with it.

The following video shows what I am going to do:
http://youtu.be/3Vae5Q7kRbs

Comment: 1)Playing the hitting animation and go to idle state if the player keeps holding Z key for a long time without releasing the key.
2)Run the hitting animation 3 times then 1 second to cooldown if the player keep holding and releasing Z key very fast.

Comment: What game was that it looked really cool. What you want to do is easy if the change I made worked. Did it work?

Comment: For now, the hitting animation can ply once if the player click and release the Z key once but the hitting animation keeps playing if the player keeps holding Z key without releasing the key..

Comment: OK Cool that is what I expected. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Line 202 has if( currentHits = hitCount) it should be if( currentHits == hitCount). I am not used to writing in C# I prefer VB. Probably complaining about assignment where it expects comparison.

Comment: I still hav the same issue.

Comment: it looks like I made the same mistake on line 206. should be currentWait == waitFrames